# How to disable zoom effect on some HTML element on page

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming

Is there any way by which i can disable pinch/zoom effect on particular HTML element present on web page.

I am creating an iframe which always sits at the bottom. I do not want it to zoom in/ zoom out when user zoom in the actual page.

Is there any meta tag or any attribute by which i can prevent the zoom on particular element?

One approach i can think of is to resize the element to nullify the zoom effect.

Thanks